# How to Access inner span or anchor text if it doesn't contain class name

Tags: webdriver

I want click on Desserts and other list items ,  by right clicking on it i am getting

```
x path : //*[@id="foodMenuPanels"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/text()
```

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="foodMenuPanels" class="food-menu-wrapper">
    <div class="food-menu-panel food-panel-results">
      <div class="food-menu-content">
        <ul class="food-menu-list"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="food-menu-panel food-panel-categories">
      <div class="food-menu-subpanel-wrapper">
        <!-- food-menu-content food-panel-categories -->

        <div class="food-menu-content food-panel-categories">
          <ul data-id="14386" class="food-menu-list">
            <li class="">
              <a href="/menu/desserts/" data-internal="14349" class="ripple">Desserts</a>

              <div class="ripples"></div>
            </li>

            <li class="">
              <a href="/menu/small-plates-snacks-appetizers/" data-internal="17145"
              class="ripple">Small Plates &amp; Snacks &amp; Appetizers</a>

              <div class="ripples"></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I gave couple of try but it is not working and i am new to the selenium tool.

Answer (score 0):

I would say go for css instead of xpath

```
a[href='/menu/desserts/']
```

Translation: find the anchor tag whose href = "/menu/desserts/"

Second anchor

```
a[href$='small-plates-snacks-appetizers/']
```

Translation: find the anchor tag whose href ends with "small-plates-snacks-appetizers/"

Comment: Thank you @saifur , it is working now. I have to put thread.sleep before using this command as it is not visible on screen. Once the menu items will be populated then only it will be visible. Is there any other way that i can wait till this text be appeared on screen ?

Comment: Yes use explicit wait. Show me the code you are using to find the element and I can suggest you some solution

Comment: @Saifur: Won't `//a[@class='ripple' and .='Desserts']` and `//a[@class='ripple' and contains(text(),'Small Plates')]` work here ?? Is there any reason you are prioritizing css here?  Just Curious.. :)

Comment: Of course it should. I was just suggesting OP to use css instead of xpath. And, the reason of priority is the performance css will give you in terms of different browser specially Internet Explorer